# How can I parse specific section data from webpage?

Tags: python, python-3.x, parsing, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to parse specific content fro mthe page using Beautiful soup, can you tell me, how can I able to do this?
Code:

```
import re
import pytz
import requests
import datetime
from flask import url_for
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from urllib.parse import urljoin


link = "http://www.espncricinfo.com/series/_/id/8038/season/2018/icc-world-cup-qualifiers/"

r = requests.get(link)
bigbash_article_html = r.text

soup = BeautifulSoup(bigbash_article_html, "html.parser")


details = soup.find("div",{"class":"module-list performers"})
bigbash_article_dict = {}


for div in details:
    image_div = div.find("div", {"class": "img-container player"})
```

I don't know how to proceed further, I'm expecting output to get as follow

Expected output:

Top run scorers:

```
[{'playerimage':'http://a.espncdn.com/combiner/i?img=/i/headshots/cricket/players/default-player-logo-500.png&h=55&w=40&scale=crop&transparent=true','playername':'TP Ura','player-details':'PNG, Right-hand bat','runs':'188','innings':'2','Average':'94.00'},..............................................................................................}]
```

same for another column
top wicket takers:

```
[{'playerimage':'http://a.espncdn.com/combiner/i?img=/i/headshots/cricket/players/default-player-logo-500.png&h=55&w=40&scale=crop&transparent=true','playername':'Ehsan Khan','player-details':'HKG, Right-arm offbreak','wickets':'9','innings':'3','Average':'12.55'},..............................................................................................}]
```

Comment: There doesn't seem to be any div on that page with that class. When you just fetch and save the HTML (with Python, or curl, or whatever) and open it in an editor, do you see such a thing? If not, BeautifulSoup obviously won't see it either.

Comment: If the page is dynamically generated—e.g., there's some JavaScript that runs and adds a bunch of "modules" full of new divs into the page after it's loaded—then you will not be able to do things this way. (You could run a JS engine from within Python, or drive a browser. Or you could manually work out what the JS code is doing and do that from within Python.) But first: Have you checked whether ESPN has an API for this, before trying to scrape it? (And, if they don't have an API, whether their ToS forbids scraping it?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Select all list items in element with classnames `sub-module` and `performers` then parse player details from each list items. *e.g.*

```
r = requests.get("http://www.espncricinfo.com/series/_/id/8038/season/2018/icc-world-cup-qualifiers/"
)

soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, "html.parser")

toprunners = soup.select(".sub-module.performers li")

def player(li):
    name_and_details = li.select_one('p')
    name = name_and_details.a
    details = name.nextSibling
    stats = li.select_one('.overall-stats p')
    img = li.select_one('.focus-image')

    return {
        'player_name': name.text,
        'player_details': details.strip(', '),
        'player_image': img.attrs['src'],
        'runs': name_and_details.nextSibling.text,
        'innings': stats.span.text,
        'average': stats.nextSibling.span.text,
    }

players = [player(li) for li in toprunners]

In[2]: print(players)

[{'player_name': 'TP Ura', 'player_details': 'PNG, Right-hand bat', 'player_image': 'http://a.espncdn.com/combiner/i?img=/i/headshots/cricket/players/default-player-logo-500.png&h=55&w=40&scale=crop&transparent=true', 'runs': '188', 'innings': '2', 'average': '94.00'}, {'player_name': 'Mohammad Nabi', 'player_details': 'AFG, Right-hand bat', 'player_image': 'http://a.espncdn.com/combiner/i?img=/i/headshots/cricket/players/25913.png&h=55&w=40&scale=crop&transparent=true', 'runs': '181', 'innings': '3', 'average': '60.33'}, {'player_name': 'SO Hetmyer', 'player_details': 'WI, Left-hand bat', 'player_image': 'http://a.espncdn.com/combiner/i?img=/i/headshots/cricket/players/default-player-logo-500.png&h=55&w=40&scale=crop&transparent=true', 'runs': '171', 'innings': '3', 'average': '57.00'}, {'player_name': 'Ehsan Khan', 'player_details': 'HKG, Right-arm offbreak', 'player_image': 'http://a.espncdn.com/combiner/i?img=/i/headshots/cricket/players/default-player-logo-500.png&h=55&w=40&scale=crop&transparent=true', 'runs': '9', 'innings': '3', 'average': '12.55'}, {'player_name': 'Mujeeb Ur Rahman', 'player_details': 'AFG, Right-arm offbreak', 'player_image': 'http://a.espncdn.com/combiner/i?img=/i/headshots/cricket/players/default-player-logo-500.png&h=55&w=40&scale=crop&transparent=true', 'runs': '8', 'innings': '3', 'average': '15.25'}, {'player_name': 'JO Holder', 'player_details': 'WI, Right-arm medium-fast', 'player_image': 'http://a.espncdn.com/combiner/i?img=/i/headshots/cricket/players/391485.png&h=55&w=40&scale=crop&transparent=true', 'runs': '7', 'innings': '3', 'average': '21.28'}]
```

Comment: How can I separate the dictionary set of list players into 3 each?

Comment: You can make use of `itertools.zip_longest` to produce a list of players split into 3 each. `splitter = [iter(players)] * 3; threes = itertools.zip_longest(*splitter); print(list(threes))`

Comment: I used a counter to do that, Your method is interesting never tried that before

Comment: @steve, you can use `a = players[:3]; b = players[3:]` to split the list.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you're searching for the wrong tag. The content you want is inside `<ul class="module-list performers">` and not `div` tag with the same class name.

The *Top Run Scorers* table is available inside the `<div id="r-0">` tag. Each player is located inside a `li` tag. You can get all the details of a player within the `li` tag.

I'll show you how to get the image, name and player-details for the *Top Run Scorers*.

```
r = requests.get('http://www.espncricinfo.com/series/_/id/8038/season/2018/icc-world-cup-qualifiers')
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'lxml')

top_run_scorers = []
for player in soup.find('div', id='r-0').find_all('li'):
    image = player.find('img')['src']
    info = player.find('div', class_='content-meta')
    name = info.find('a').text
    details = info.p.contents[-1]
    top_run_scorers.append({'playerimage': image, 'playername': name, 'player-details': details})

print(top_run_scorers)
```

Output:

```
[{'player-details': ', PNG, Right-hand bat',
  'playerimage': 'http://a.espncdn.com/combiner/i?img=/i/headshots/cricket/players/default-player-logo-500.png&h=55&w=40&scale=crop&transparent=true',
  'playername': 'TP Ura'},
 {'player-details': ', AFG, Right-hand bat',
  'playerimage': 'http://a.espncdn.com/combiner/i?img=/i/headshots/cricket/players/25913.png&h=55&w=40&scale=crop&transparent=true',
  'playername': 'Mohammad Nabi'},
 {'player-details': ', WI, Left-hand bat',
  'playerimage': 'http://a.espncdn.com/combiner/i?img=/i/headshots/cricket/players/default-player-logo-500.png&h=55&w=40&scale=crop&transparent=true',
  'playername': 'SO Hetmyer'}]
```

Comment: @steve, SO is not a code writing service, so, I'm not going to show you how to get all the details. Using the above code, try to get the rest of the details. I guess I've shown you how to *proceed further*.

Comment: can you explain me what does this line do details = info.p.contents[-1]? precisely contents[-1]

Comment: Try printing the contents of any element using `.contents`. you'll see a list of all its contents. The details you wanted were present in the last index of the list. That's why [-1]